# PHP repeat progress after waking up

Tags: php

I want to repeatedly check a variable every time php wakes up from sleep(). Further, if 3 minutes have passed without finding a particular variable then the function should stop checking. How would I go about this? This is the code I have thus far:

```
<?php
  $file = file_get_contents("file.txt");
  if($file == 0){
    sleep(3);// then go back to $file
  } else {
    //stuff i want
  }
?>
```

Comment: post your code.. how far you have tried..

Comment: ...and please explain better what you're trying to do

Comment: How will the content of $file change after 3 seconds? what could possibily change it? (file_get_contents isn't called again)

Comment: from different file it does write 1 or some other content than 0 into it when some other progress is complete

Comment: What is the "stuff I want" part? If it's sending something to the browser, this isn't going to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to keep doing something until something else happens, you want a loop. You have two things to check to see if you should exit the loop: the file variable and the length of time. You need to add a variable to keep track of the time, or you need to check the time each time you loop and compare it to the start time.

```
<?php

     $file = file_get_contents("file.txt");
     $timesChecked = 0;
     while($file == 0 and $timesChecked < 60)
     {
         sleep(3);
         $timesChecked++;
         $file = file_get_contents("file.txt");
     } 
     if($file != 0)
     {
          // stuff i want
     } else {
          // 3 minutes elapsed
     }
 ?>
```

Comment: Note that this function will, at a minimum, run for 6000 seconds, or 100 minutes. Also, note that sleep may not return in exactly three seconds depending on how the OS decides to handle processes. Therefore even if the $timesChecked is set to < 60, this can still run for more than three minutes by an indeterminate amount.

Comment: @NathanielFord: Thank you. I was thinking sleep() took microseconds or something, and then I did the math wrong. :) You're absolutely right about the imprecision of this method. Better to compare against `time()` if that 3 minutes is a precision requirement.   http://us.php.net/time

Comment: how to make the page load normally without waiting for $file to become something else

Comment: @LiliAbedinpour Note that you *can't* send a response if you're waiting for something else to happen. You'll probably have to have an ajax call to a separate php page that happens periodically, waiting for an update.

Comment: @Lili: if you don't want to wait, don't check the file. If you want to load the page and THEN check the file for three minutes, you'll want to look into javascript, AJAX, and jquery. You'd run a similar loop in javascript in the browser - not in PHP. That loop would run an ajax request to a PHP script on the server that would check the file.

Comment: What Scott said is a very good description of the flow there!

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
  //This function returns false if the time elapses without finding the variable.
  //Otherwise it executes what you want to do. It could instead return true if that makes sense.
  function waitForContent($filename) {
    $timeElapsed = 0;
    $lastTry = 0;//the time the file was last checked for contents

    $filehandler = file_get_contents($filename);
    while ($filehandler == 0) {
      $currentTime = microtime();//current time in microseconds
      $timeElapsed = $currentTime - $lastTry;//Note this may not be three seconds, due to how sleep works.
      $lastTry = currentTime;//update the time of the last trye
      if ($timeElapsed > (180 * 1000)) {//if three minutes has passed, quit.
        return false;
      }
      sleep(3);
      $filehandler = file_get_contents($filename);//update file handler
    }

    stuffIWantToDo();//stuff you want to do function.
  }
```